# Elderly man sending postcards to random addresses during wartime

Tags: identify-this-movie, short-films

I'm trying to identify this short film I watched a while ago. Here's what I remember;

- I watched it on YouTube around 2012/2013 (it was very professionally done, and won a few awards)
- It was live action and in colour
- The plot consisted of an old man sending postcards to random addresses around the world and see how long it took for them to return / see if he got any replies
- Every day he would wait for the postman to arrive
- It was based around the ending of a war (world war 2 / cold war - I can't remember specifically)
- From what I remember, it wasn't based in the United States (this could be wrong)
- In the end, the man got taken away by the army for "being a spy" due to the amount of postcards he sent (or a factor of the postcards)
- The man died in a plane crash after being taken away by the army

I hope this is enough information for you guys, if not, I'll try and remember some more.

Comment: Per meta discussions and the help page, spoilers in the body of a question are not needed, especially on an identify this question.

Comment: Was it live action? Was it in color? (BTW, if you watched on it YT when you were logged in, you can search for it in your watch history - though it might take a while. YT archives every video you've ever watched.)

Comment: Hi @Walt - It was live action colour, yes. I swap between many Google accounts and I'm really unsure which one I was logged in on when I watched - though I'll search my primary ones after work - thanks for the tip!

Comment: You don't happen to remember what any of the awards were, or even looked like (their icons)?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remember @CGCampbell `:(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found your short: It's [Envelope](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2174736/combined) from 2012 with Kevin Spacey.

> Evgeniy started writing fake letters since he was 6 when he tried writing one to his imaginary friend. Throughout his lifetime, he has accumulated a letter from every country, except New Zealand. He writes a letter to a seemingly fake person in a seemingly fake city in New Zealand. After 4 weeks, he receives a letter back from the fake person stating that Evgeniy and the person have in fact met in real life. A lieutenant comes and searches his house to find a secret code hidden among the envelopes. Evgeniy is shocked and the lieutenant travels with him to board a plane later on. While Evgeniy and the lieutenant are traveling, Tanya (Evgeniy's wife) finds a letter in which the person from New Zealand proves to be true and states that Evgeniy will die in a plane.

It was based on a [true story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yevgeny_Petrov_%28writer%29). Here it is in its entirety:

Answer (score 1):

Sounds similar to **The Letter writer**. But your description is so vague it may be something else. This was a short 12 minute film in 2012 LDS film festival. Hope you find what you are looking for

Comment: No offense, but I don't think the OP's description is vague at all.

Comment: None taken, i just said that based on number of answers(zero basically) it got.

Comment: Hey thanks @Shrilekha - unfortunately this isn't it (though it does look interesting)

Comment: I agree that this is actually one of the better written identify-this questions. Unfortunately, it's about a short film, which are generally not as widely viewed as feature films, and this question may take a long while to be correctly answered due to that. (waiting for someone who saw it to read the question.)